# multiple level unorderd list hierarchy in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this html and css code, i hve done in css to show and hide, i want this to be done in jquery for click event and padding left and right for the seccond and third level unroderd list has to be increased than its parent, If i add one more unorderd list then it has to add some padding dynamically and i shouldn't have to add any css for that.

```
<ul class="delete">
                <li><a>1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>1a</a></li>
                        <li><a>1b</a></li>
                        <li><a>1c</a></li>
                        <li><a>1d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>2a</a></li>
                        <li><a>2b</a></li>
                        <li><a>2c</a></li>
                        <li><a>2d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a>3a</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>3aa</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a>3aaa</a></li>
                                        <li><a>3aab</a></li>
                                        <li><a>3aac</a></li>
                                        <li><a>3aad</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a>3ab</a></li>
                                <li><a>3ac</a></li>
                                <li><a>3ad</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a>3b</a></li>
                        <li><a>3c</a></li>
                        <li><a>3d</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a>4</a></li>                   
            </ul>

.delete li a:hover {
background-color: #008000;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
 padding:0px;
 }

.delete {
   width: 300px;
 }

.delete > li {
    margin: 15px 0px;
  }

.delete > li > a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 10px;
   border: 2px solid #000000;
   }

.delete > li > ul > li > a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 20px;
   border: 2px solid #000000;
  }

.delete > li > ul > li > ul > li > a {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px 40px;
   border: 2px solid #000000;
  }

.delete > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 60px;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
  }

.delete  li ul {
   display: none;
  }

.delete li:hover > ul{
   display: block;
  }
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madz_1010/LLLdd/)

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: i want the solution in jquery...

Comment: http://www.egrappler.com/multi-level-hierarchical-jquery-menu-jqsimplemenu/ See this link.

Comment: "I want" is not a question, it's a statement. A *question* would be "How can I make jQuery do..." Also, you should show us your own attempts and explain what doesn't work, and/or where you got stuck. We'll *help*, but we're not going to do your work *for* you.

Comment: I guess I really didn't understand the question because I fail to see why the selected answer would be marked as the correct answer.  It doesn't seem to address at all the OP's requirement: "i want this to be done in jquery for click event" and as Bhavik points out setting the padding on a nested ul is unnecessary as it automatically handles the indentation.  It's a lot of code that essentially can be replaced with a single css rule.

Answer (score 1):

It will probably be easier to use a plugin to accomplish your task. User @PawanLakhara suggested  [jQSimpleMenu](http://www.egrappler.com/multi-level-hierarchical-jquery-menu-jqsimplemenu/).

Another possible solution is to use a recursive function which iterates over the list items and sets the css on each anchor element:

```
function iterateItems($context) {
    $context.children('ul').each(function(){
        $(this).children('li').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var p = $context.data('li-padding');
            $this.data('li-padding', ((!p) ? 10 : p + 10));
            $this.children('a:first').css({
                'display': 'block',
                'padding': '0px ' + $this.data('li-padding') + 'px',
                'border': '2px solid #000000'
            });            
            iterateItems($(this));
        }); 
    });
}


iterateItems($('body'));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tHdcg/)

Answer (score 0):

***[`Live result here`](http://jsfiddle.net/LLLdd/2/embedded/result/)***
*jQuery Code*

```
$('.delete li a').click(function (e) {
    $('.delete .innerList').not($(this).parents('.innerList')).slideUp();
    $(this).next('.innerList').slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The list-items sizes and padding's will be managed by own you need not worry about it.. As we have bounded the width of the parent ul

```
.delete {
    width: 300px;
}
```

*Result looks something like this*
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I understood the question to have two parts:

1. Make the menu expand on click event
2. Make the indention without having to add additional css

The previous answer seems to be the closest to my understanding.  Assuming that you want the items to remain expanded unless specifically clicked to close, you can use this instead:

```
$('.delete').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('expandnext');
});
```

and change your css to:

```
.delete li a:hover {
    background-color: #008000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
.delete {
    width: 300px;
}
.delete li {
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
.delete li li {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.delete li a {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
}
.delete li ul {
    display: none;
}
.delete ul.expandnext {
  display: block;
}
```

**EDIT:** Inspired by Bhavik's point about handling indentation.

[Edit to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/RnznR/)